# Powerbuilder 12.5 Migration

Tags: powerbuilder

PB12.5 using SNC driver with `dateformat=mm/dd/yyyy` and SQL Server user date `format=mdy` as well. So far so good.

The problem comes when the user's regional setting is `dd/mm/yyyy`. So passing an argument of type Date in PB12.5 (say in DW using stored procedure) will always be in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, but SNC driver is expecting `mm/dd/yyyy`, causing an error.

Is there anyway of formatting a 'datetime' type variable to use `mm/dd/yyyy` format instead, in this case ????? No use turning it into a string with format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect this has nothing to do with database or connection settings; this is a UI issue. It sounds like you're after a universal answer, but it depends on the control you're talking about. For example, the answer for a DW editmask is different than for a DW edit.

And, if you use date or datetime data types (both on the client and the server), passing values back and forth should never be impacted by format; formatting is for display of values only, AFAIK.

Good luck.